# Can't set variable from $_POST

Tags: php, variables, post, global-variables

I can't set a variable from a post array.

I have a simple form with a hidden field in it:
    `<input name="sid" type="hidden" id="sid" value="<?=$sid?>">`

This hidden field gets sent off to a second file (exec.php) where I have the following code:

```
$sid = $_POST['sid'];
```

For some reason, when trying to set $sid, it gets a NULL value. For haha's, I ran the following:

```
foreach($_POST as $var => $value)
{
echo $var . ' : ' . $value . "<br>";
}
```

This provided a correct value of 1938 for sid. I've looked at this for 3 hours and can't find what is happening. I expect something extremely stupid...any thoughts?

---

Here is the form on enter.php

```
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="exec.php">
     <input name="sid" type="hidden" id="sid" value="<? echo($sid); ?>">
     <input name="ticket_totals" type="hidden" id="ticket_totals" value="<?=$ticket_totals?>">
     <input name="emp" type="hidden" id="emp" value="<?=$emp?>">
     <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Close">
    </form>
```

Here is the POST output on exec.php:
type : Other
ticket_totals : 0
emp : 105
sid : 1939
submit : Submit

---

Okay - this was poor syntax on my part but now I'm curious as to why.

I left out quotation marks - the solution is as simple as this:
$sid = $_POST["sid"]

Now it works like a champ.

Any takers on why? I'd guess there is a setting in the php.ini that requires the quotes. Strangely enough, I have other variables called from the POST array that i'm not using quotes for and they're working fine...

Comment: Place an `var_dump($sid);` directly below `$sid = $_POST['sid'];`. Your error certainly lies elsewhere.

Comment: are you able to cut and paste the  output from foreach($_POST as $var => $value), so we can verify there isn't a typo or something as that seems rather strange.

Comment: are you sure that output is correct, the following form fields are missing from it. shift_id, emp and your POST output shows another field "type" which is not on your form

Comment: @bumperbox they're correct - i cut out a bunch of other form fields from the post...there's a lot of forms on the enter.php file and i edited them out of the post for reading aesthetics. my ocd was kicking in - i like neat lines unfortunately.

Comment: i've updated my original post - problem a: fixed. problem b...why?

Comment: If you're using Sessions, a constant "SID" holds the current session id - `$_POST[SID]` would resolve to `$_POST[eb12....]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Console in [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to inspect the POST request to see what is the `sid` value that is being sent.

If the `sid` value in request is ok, use `var_dump($_POST["sid"]);` to see the results on the server.

**EDIT**: it's considered good PHP style to use the quotes when accessing the associative array because quote-less keys are indistinguishable from constants:

```
define('myVar',3);
echo $array[myVar]; // retrieves $array[3], not $array['myVar'];
```

Comment: @thebarless by came through OK you mean the sid value is sent ok? Then the problem is obiously on the server side. Try using var_dump($_POST) to see what did you received.

Comment: edited my initial post - vardump gives me this

type : Other 
ticket_totals : 0 
emp : 105 
sid : 1939 
submit : Submit

Comment: @thebarless so that means that the $_POST contains the correct value of sid. $_POST["sid"] should get you the value you sent with POST.

Comment: i agree - that's where i'm stumped.

Comment: i've updated my original post - problem a: fixed. problem b...why?

Comment: i think there's a downvote nazi on here - oh well, i appreciate your help

Comment: That downvote was from me, for your "answer" really not being an answer at all - I've undownvoted you since your edit changed that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to echo the `$sid` instead of the `<?=`:

```
// Change that
<input name="sid" type="hidden" id="sid" value="<?=$sid?>">

// With that
<input name="sid" type="hidden" id="sid" value="<?php echo $sid; ?>">
```

also for the test time try to change the input type from hidden to text in order to be 100% sure the `$sid` contains a value.

Comment: tried switching to echo and no change, switched the field to text and no change... and once again, when I run the post variables on the exec.php file, I get sid : 1939

Comment: So if you try that will print out anything ? <p>My SID : <?php echo $sid; ?>; <input name="sid" type="hidden" id="sid" value="<?php echo $sid; ?>">

Comment: the `<?=` is shorthand for `<?php echo`

Comment: @thebarless has a good point with that - don't use the short PHP tags because they are not generally recommended.

Comment: I know taht @Brombomb, but some times is not enebled by default in PHP settings

Comment: what's strange is this just happened out of nowhere - this was a functioning script as of yesterday. it has been functioning this way for almost a year

Comment: Did you try any of the above solutions ? We already have give you several solutions in order to debug your script and you have not give any answer depending on the above

Comment: And what is the debuging result ? You have not yet give us feedback

Comment: @MerianosNikos this information was provided in above posts - using the echo command doesn't affect it. outputting a vardump on post supplies the correct value. Firebug also shows that the variable is going through post. the only thing making sense at this point is the $sid = $_POST[sid]; is where the problem exists

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4285/discussion-between-thebarless-and-merianos-nikos)

Comment: i've updated my original post - problem a: fixed. problem b...why?

Answer (score 0):

Using quotes for associative array keys is mandatory, and while it may work without them, it's incorrect and erratic behavior is expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, trying to use $_POST[sid] as a variable. I'm am thinking that "sid" is a reserved or restricted variable name, because I changed my variable to $_POST[snid] and it worked just fine. This was my code

```
$sid = $_POST[sid];
$recipient = "($sid) ($_POST[sid])";
if ($_POST[sid] > 0)
{
    $recipient = "It Worked";
}
print $recipient;
```

When I posted "&sid=15", the result was:

```
() (15)
```

Unbelievable. Impossible, right? All I did was change from using "sid" as the index to "snid", and it worked no problem.

So, don't ever use $_POST[sid].